# CodeIgniter URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to rewrite the URL of a CodeIgniter application, though it doesn't seem to work.
I have the following things set;

```
$route['pages/(:num)/(:any)'] = "pages/view/$1/$2";
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Then I have the following .htaccess;

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php/pages/view/$1/$2 [L]
```

It just says the page is not found (an Apache error, not CodeIgniter).
It works when I browse to the original link (http://domain.tld/index.php/pages/view/1/welcome) but not when browsing to the 'desired' link (http://domain.tld/pages/1/welcome).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to have htaccess to remove index.php from url and it should work

Comment: Not quite, it's not just removing the 'index.php' but also the name of the method; view.

Comment: Have you checked the apache logs to find out what apache is rewriting this to? Additionally you may want the non greedy version of the match for $1 ie `^pages/(.*?)/(.*)$`

Comment: I don't want to sound too dumb, but apparently my server did not support htaccess yet, I changed the apache vhost and now it's working with a little bit of tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$route["pages/(.*)/(.*)"] = "pages/view/$1/$2";
//and your htacess, remove your current rule and
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Figured it out using this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you are missing a `?` in your RewriteRule?

```
# Substitute " >>?<< " with "?". It's there to point you to the change.
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php >>?<< /pages/view/$1/$2 [L]
```

Comment: Not that, Codeigniter uses the slash format, plus op states that manually using the rewritten version works